# В docker контейнере не запускается php7.2-fpm

Tags: php, docker, centos, php7.2

очень надеюсь на вашу помощь, тк в unix еще новичок.

Есть приложение, которое надо поставить. Это связка из 2х образов docker.
Первый образ с MongoDB, второй с nginx и php.

Все делаю по инструкции:
https://github.com/passwork-me/manuals-ru/blob/master/Docker.md

Проблема состоит в том, что когда я захожу на вебсервер получаю ошибку 502.
Я посмотрел лог nginx пишет следующее:

```
2019/07/24 10:35:51 [crit] 143#143: *1 connect() to unix:/var/run/php/php.sock failed (2: No such file or directory) while connecting to upstream, client: 192.168.100.7, server: localhost, request: "GET / HTTP/1.1", upstream: "fastcgi://unix:/var/run/php/php.sock:", host: "192.168.100.8"
```

В директории `/var/run/php/` пусто.

Пишу `service php7.2-fpm status` и получаю : `php-fpm7.2 is not running Illegal instruction (core dumped)` .

Попытка запустить сервис ни к чему не приводит.

В логах php пусто и никак не получается заставить php писать этот лог.

> Пока что для меня проблема выглядит так:
>
> Php не стартует, поэтому файл с соккетом не создается, поэтому nginx
> ругается.

Я неопытен, скину все конфиги, которые будут нужны для решения проблемы.

Comment: а разрешения у wwwdata (user apatch) есть разрешение chmod -777

Comment: @Bloom уточните пожалуйста разрешения на какую папку?

Comment: /var/run/php/  //

Comment: Я стянул этот докер, зашел в него, вручную запустил сервисы, они поднимаются без проблем. Вы уверены что у вас корректно прокинуты все конфиги ? `Попытка запустить сервис ни к чему не приводит.` а как именно вы пытаетесь запустить вручную сервис ?

Comment: Всем большое спасибо, как оказалось нужно было пересобрать PHP, тк он был собран под другой процессор.